# ¿Como puedo instalar PHP en Ubuntu?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, bash, php7

Tal y como dice la pregunta.

Estoy intentando usar **Laravel** para un proyecto y me pidieron explícitamente que utilice un Sistema Operativo basado en **Linux** para ello.

Lo que pasa es que ya he intendado con **Kali** y no pude. En Debian ni siquiera lo pude hacer correr. Mi última opción es Ubuntu, y este fue el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta instalación de **Ubuntu** es completamente nueva, recién instalado. No tiene literalmente nada extra aparte de su instalación por defecto y tengo problemas con instalar **PHP**. Busqué tutoriales, pero ninguno da una respuesta clara.

Probé con `hhvm`, me dice que no hay paquete, probé con `php-fpm` y más de lo mismo.

¿Alguién sabe como instalar **PHP** en **Ubuntu**?

Solo quiero eso.

Comment: Por favor lee esto https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-en-ubuntu-18-04-la-pila-lamp-linux-apache-mysql-y-php-es

Comment: Tiene que ver con los repositorios y los nombres que estás usando, ese espacio entre php y 7.2 ¿estás seguro que así dice la documentación? Si vas a iniciar en temas de GNU/Linux leer la documentación es como respirar, te mantienes vivo si mantienes tus pulmones funcionando. Ánimos que ahora en YouTube existen miles de videotutoriales, inclusive en español :D

Answer (score 1):

### Instalación de PHP

Para instalar PHP en **Ubuntu** debes escribir en la terminal el siguiente comando:

```sh
sudo apt install php
```

Y si las dependencias no se cumplen una vez hecho lo anterior, debes escribir:

```sh
sudo apt -f install
```

Con lo anterior, le solicitamos a `apt` que corrija las dependencias no satisfechas.

#### Importante tomar en cuenta:

Si vas a correr **Laravel** debes instalar como mínimo, además de **PHP**, un servidor Web (en este caso, usaremos **Apache**), un motor de base de datos, además de `composer`:

```sh
sudo apt install apache2 mysql-server composer
```

Donde `apache2` es el servidor Web donde correrá **Laravel**, `mysql-server` el motor de base de datos y `composer` el programa que ayudará satisfacer las dependencias en **Laravel**.

Más importante aún es, que si las dependencias no se satisfacen debes ejecutar siempre este comando:

```sh
sudo apt -f install
```

### Caso MySQL Server en Ubuntu

En las nuevas versiones del servidor de base de datos **MySQL Server**, cuando se realiza su instalación no se le solicitará al usuario que configure una contraseña. De hecho, debe crearse manualmente y la forma de hacerlo es:

```sh
sudo mysql
```

Una vez se realice lo anterior deberá definirse el usuario, la contraseña y los privilegios de la siguiente manera:

```sql
-- Creamos el usuario:
CREATE USER 'nombre_de_usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña';

-- Proporcionamos su privilegio:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* 'nombre_de_usuario'@'localhost';

-- Actualizando privilegios
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Para el caso de los privilegios, debe tomarse encuenta que (`*.*`) significa literalmente esto: *proporciónale todos los privilegios de todas las bases de datos y tablas al usuario `nombre_de_usuario` del host `localhost`*.

Comment: En el caso de `Ubuntu` solo debe escribir `sudo apt install php`, ya que con esta acción se elige automáticamente la versión más reciente de PHP.

Comment: Oh no, por favor apache no. En la comunidad de Laravel preferimos NGINX.

Comment: Qué curioso comentario, Shaz, por qué lo dices? Qué diferencia hay?? Saludos!

Comment: @Shaz, ¿cuál es el problema de usar Laravel sobre Apache? Lo importante es que la página hecha en ese _Framework_ pueda correr. Por otro lado, no se trata de un entorno de **producción** (no es una infraestructura), sino de **desarrollo** y la razón por la que recomendé **Apache** fue su facilidad de uso, instalación y configuración al igual con **XAMPP**. Sin embargo, hay infraestructuras montadas con **Apache**, es decir, que la mayor parte del Internet corre sobre él.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿a qué se debió el voto negativo?

Comment: Antes que nada, si leen bien mi comentario anterior, verán que nunca dije que había un «problema» con Laravel y Apache. Simplemente dije que en la comunidad de Laravel **preferimos** NGINX. No conozco un «buen» desarrollador de Laravel que use Apache, creo que esa palabra dejó de existir hace rato en el vocabulario de muchos grandes desarrolladores con quienes tengo contacto. En cuanto a la discusión de NGINX vs. Apache, yo pensé que eso ya estaba claro, es como si quisiéramos discutir entre si usar el correo electrónico o enviar la carta físicamente para una comunicación con Japón.

Comment: (Perdón por la demora, en responder)

MUCHAS GRACIAS, lo acabo de probar y sirve !!! Ahora trataré de instalar laravel y levantar un sitio simple. 

Me salvaste la vida, muchas gracias

Comment: Por último, trabajé muchísimo tiempo con Apache, en proyectos de todos los tamaños, y sinceramente, no le veo lo fácil en cuanto a su uso. Fácil es NGINX, que tiene un montón de configuraciones implícitas que en Apache es todo un karma. En cuanto al voto negativo, lo emití en su momento porque el autor de la respuesta decía que se **TENÍA** que instalar Apache, y NO, no es así, podríamos instalar Nginx, Litespeed, Lighthttpd, entre otros y perfectamente funcionaría Laravel.

Comment: Por cierto, @DavidE.LunaM. te veo pelear mucho por un voto negativo, pero ni siquiera has votado positivamente la pregunta que estás respondiendo. En teoría, si la respondes, es porque está bien redactada y explicada, ¿no?

Comment: @Shaz, si lees mis comentarios puedes observar que hice dos observaciones. Una en cada comentario y se puede observar que no anda peleando. En cuanto al voto negativo, sería posiblemente la misma pregunta que te habrías hecho.

Comment: En cuanto al voto positivo, no lo hago en seguida. Soy meticuloso con eso y por tanto, analizo bien antes de hacerlo. Es decir, no me gusta votar a la ligera ni positivo ni negativo. En este caso, le acabo de dar `+1` a la pregunta que respondí. Pero normalmente, soy meticuloso con eso y analizo antes de actuar.

Comment: La próxima vez también puedes analizar antes de responder.

Comment: Siempre lo hago y por eso puedes observar que la redacción es clara. Sin embargo,  no quiere decir que surjan imperfecciones que no puedan corregirse con la edición. Eso se puede sugerir en lugar de calificarse una respuesta como tal de forma apresurada sin sugerir que se realice una acción.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103589/discussion-between-david-e-luna-m-and-shaz).